# the <a> tag in my carousel is showing dead link in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

the anchor tag in my carousel is showing dead link. i.e. cannot hover over it. everything else works fine. but the link is not working inside the div. i have used all the files from bootstrap and have not made any changes to the scripts.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/slide1.jpg'); background-size:cover;"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Caption 1</h1>
        <p></p>
        <a href="#" class="read">Read More &raquo;</a>
        <br/>
        <div class="tech">
            <img src="images/tech.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/slide2.jpg'); background-size:cover;"></div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Caption 2</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/slide3.jpg'); background-size:cover;"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Caption 3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You post your question for second time...

Comment: Please **do not** post questions multiple times. If the first post was voted down, try to edit it first. Posting the same content will have the same result.

Comment: That said, I believe this question is of higher quality than the original.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow and did not have much idea on editing posts. i realized there was much mistake in the question itself and not have enough explanation in my previous question. that is why i posted this again

Comment: so whats your question? .. please make edit to your question

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments provided to patel.milanb's answer, the author points to a live example of his problem: http://itechnepal.com/new_site//

**The issue:** The `<ol>` containing the carousel indicators overlaps a link, which therefor is not clickable.

Removing `bottom: 10px;` from `.carousel-indicators` will solve the issue.

**CSS:**

```
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    /*bottom: 10px; <- remove this*/
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 15;
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: -30%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As what i could understand from your question.

```
link is not working inside DIV
```

I would say you did not provided any link to your `<a>` tag

```
<a href="#" class="read">
```

replace with:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="read">
```

Update: remove your style from css

```
.carousel-indicators {
   top: 180px;
}

look into bootstrap.css line no: 6590
```

OR remove `bottom: 10px;` from class `.carousel-indicators` `Line no: 6523`

Comment: i have tried that too. the problem is i cannot hover over the read more link. you can see it on http://itechnepal.com/new_site/. the "read more" link is not working

Comment: what do you mean i can not hover over the link... can you see Read More... on your page or not

Comment: @user3139019 That's because of `<ol class=carousel-indicators>` is overlapping the link. If you remove it, the link works as expected. Remove the `bottom: 10px;` from `.carousel-indicators` to fix this issue.